# Multiple services fail after kernel panic recover

Tags: debian, boot, services, kernel-panic, systemctl

The last week i crash debian trying to update python3, so i had the brillant idea of:

```
apt-get remove python3
```

then python an a huge ist of packages was unistalled and system reboot in kenel panic.

I can repair the system by instaling a list of packeges using a debian live CD.

Now the kernel panic is gone, but the system starts with the erros:

```
    [FAILED] Failed to start Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
see 'systemctl status systemd-tempfiles-setup.dev.services fo details 

[FAILED] Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistant Storage.
see 'systenctl status systend-journal-flush.service' for details

[FAILED] Failed to start Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
see 'systemctl status systemd-tempfiles-setup.dev.services fo details 

[FAILED] Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistant Storage.
see 'systenctl status systend-journal-flush.service' for details

[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces
se 'systemctl status networking.service' for details

[FAILED] Failed to start Login Service.
See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service for details

[FAILED] Failed to start Modem Service.
see 'systemctl status ModemManager.service' for details

[FAILED] to start Accounts Service
see 'systemctl sttus rtkit-daemon.service' for details

[FAILED] to start Realtimekit Scheduling Policy
see 'systemctl status rtkit-daemon.service' for details.

[FAILED] to start Bluetooth.service.
see 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.

[FAILED] to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
see 'systemctl to start avahi-daemon.service' for details

[FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager.
See 'systeml status NetworkManager.service' for details

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online.
```

I do not know  how to process.

Thank you very much

Comment: If you know the uninstalled packages, you could reinstall python3 + the missing packages. If you don't know what is missing, reinstallation of Debian with the same settings is an option. Do a data backup first! If you are ever asked to remove lots of packages, just say no.

Comment: thank you for answering, i only can access to the shell uisng the live CD but i can not run "apt-get update" and if i try "su -"  says "su must be excueted into a terminal"

Comment: If you have a data backup, the fastest way is a re-install, booting from your live CD, especially as your current system doesn't even have a working internet connection. Your live CD could also be used to mount your current disk/SSD for temporary access to your old system or data files.